# Python's smtplib sendmail is inserting line feed

Tags: python, email, carriage-return, smtplib

I am using smtplib sendmail and \n (line feed) is being added where there was just \r (carriage return).

This corrupts the file for use with the UNIX tnef utility.  How can I keep the line feed from being added?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know this? Have you checked with a packet sniffer?

Comment: I checked before and after send.  I don't need a packet sniffer because the server is localhost.

Comment: Email bodies shouldn't be that sensitive - it's probably just trying to enforce standard email line-ending conventions. Try encoding the data as a Base64 attachment.

Comment: FWIW, I am using the unix tnef utility on the emails. It is tnef that is super-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email servers are free to change line endings IIRC. They could be various platforms.

If you are transmitting an attachment, use a suitable encoding such as Base64.

Comment: This would work but I am processing emails and cannot change them.  Thanks for the info about IIRC.

Comment: Well, just change them back (after you have checked that my memory was right, and mail transfer may arbitrarily change linefeeds in non-encoded data)

Comment: Lol, that is what I will be doing while I test.  Was hoping there was a better solution.  I cannot automate because there were some <CLRF> in the original.